# List All functions in file Python

Tags: python

I have a file structure:

```
A
|
main.py
|_B
  |a_funcs.py
```

`A` is the main folder while `B` is a sub-folder inside `A`. In my `main.py` filer, I have `from B.a_funcs import *`. This statement imports all functions from the `a_func.py` file. Is it possible to list out all the functions inside that `a_func.py` file`? How do I do that?

I tried `dir(a_func)` but that says a_func is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you didn't explicitly import the name a_func. Instead of `from B.a_func import *` (which creates potential namespace collisions) do `from B import a_func`, and then call functions with `a_func.`. This is better practice, and will let you do what you want.

Comment: And to list out all functions in that file you simply do `dir(a_func)`